# Open Form faster & remove "System.Data.DataRowView" flicker from Combobox data binding

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have plenty Comboboxes on my form (around 20), and all of them are displaying items from different tables of my DB. If I put all code on Form_Load event then Form opens very slow. So I tried to paste code in different varieties, and currently I'm stuck at Combobox_Enter event - now Form loads fast, but when I click on drop-down of combobox I see sometimes "System.Data.DataRowView" flickering before items are loaded in Combobox. Is there any way to achieve both - fast Form opening & Combobox loading Items without flickering ?....So far I tested with Form_Activate,Form_GotFocus(not working) and Combobox_GotFocus,Combobox_MouseHover,Combobox_Click(not exactly perfect). This is an example of how I bind my Comboboxes:

```
 Private Sub Combobox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Combobox1.Enter

        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT Name from MyTable"

        Dim dtb As New DataTable()

        Using con As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection("Data Source=MyDB;User Id=Lucky;Password=MyPassword;")

            Try

                con.Open()

                Using dad As New OracleDataAdapter(SQL, con)
                    dad.Fill(dtb)
                End Using

                Combobox1.DataSource = dtb
                Combobox1.DisplayMember = "Name"

                con.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Finally
                con.Dispose()
            End Try

            Combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1

        End Using

End Sub
```

I also tried with declaring " Public con As OracleConnection", but output is same as I have It now.

Any help appreaciated !

Comment: You might consider starting a `BackgroundWorker` in the `Load` event handler and loading the data in the background, using `ReportProgress` and `ProgressChanged` to populate each `ComboBox` as the data becomes available.  You could even use individual `Tasks` for each query.

Comment: Ok, never heard of that. I'll take a look of this. Code works fine in Form_Load event, no flickering but forms opens very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding a `ComboBox` or the like, you should pretty much ALWAYS set the `DataSource` last.  You are not and that's why you see "System.Data.DataRowView" displayed.

When you bind a list to a `ComboBox`, the control will display data from the column or property specified in the `DisplayMember` if there is one, otherwise it will call `ToString` on each item.  In your code, you first set the `DataSource` and, at that point, the `DisplayMember` is not set so the control calls `ToString` on each item.  The result of that is "System.Data.DataRowView".  When you then set the `DisplayMember`, those values that the control just went to the trouble of generating and displaying are discarded and the `DisplayMember` is used to get new values.

Even if you weren't seeing that effect, you'd still be wasting your control's time generating values that you don't want.  ALWAYS set the `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember` or the like before setting the `DataSource` in code unless you have a specific reason not to.  The only reason that I'm aware of is when you're binding a `CheckedListBox`, which has an issue when `DataSource` is set last.

By the way, shouldn't you have a test there to only retrieve data if there is no data already loaded? You don't want to reload data if the user returns to the same control, do you?

Comment: Adding Datasource last doesn't do anything, I still see "System.Data.DataRowView" flickering. About test - yes that should be fine, but how to do this ?

Comment: It works now, I had 1 thing more that I needed to remove in code. About test you were mentioning about retrieving data - you meant that by Backgroundworker or something else ? I could use that, It would be better.